# How to add multiple names in condition of scope

Tags: javascript

I am fiddling with this to add more then one user. How do i add more names in this condition without breaking it? i am simply trying to check if scope.myName is equal to Paul jackson or John Ambers.

```js
  if ($scope.myName == "jackson, paul") {
                   
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain more thoroughly what you are trying to do?

Comment: is this valid   if ($scope.myName == "jackson, paul" | "ambers, john") { alert("test");
                   
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a logical OR [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in your if-statements condition:

```
if ($scope.myName == "jackson, paul" || $scope.myName == "ambers, john") {
    ...                   
}
```